# Check if words in a cell appear in a list ...but the words can be out of sequence

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a whitelist of job titles e.g. Systems Engineer

I want to check if cells contain those words e.g.

'Systems Product Engineer' would be fine, it contains 'systems' and 'engineer' and the fact it has 'Product' does not matter

Systems Manager would not be ok since it only contains 'Systems' and not 'Engineer'

Is this possible with a formula?

I have tried:

```
=IF(MATCH(job title,whitelist of job titles,0),"Yes")
```

This does not work

I have also tried:

=COUNTIF(whitelist of job titles,job title)>0)
Also not working

I have also tried:

```
=IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(whitelist of job titles,job title,0))>0,"yes","no")
```

Also not working

**Finally i tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(whitelist of job titles,job title)))>0
```

This kind of works if the words systems engineer appear next to each other but a word in the middle like systems product engineer it will not work**

Finally i tried text to columns to break up the job title into its component words and use these formulas across the range of component words.

Many Thanks!

Comment: ¿The whitelist is inside a single cell?

Comment: your white list must have the words separated or it will not see it as a match.  Put System and Engineer it separate cells in the lookup range.

Answer (score 0):

If your whitelist of jobs is inside a single cell, you can check if job titles got those words, but **in same order**. Check it:

[image]

The formula at D1 and drag down is:

`=IF(COUNTIF(C1;"*"&REPLACE($A$1;" ";"*")&"*")<>0;"Yes";"No")`

It works but **only if job title contains the words in same order**. Cells C5 and C7 contains the words, but in opposite order, and the formula does not work properly. You would need your whitelist in reverse order, in this case, `Engineer Systems`

If your whitelist is in separated cells, then you can combine SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIF to count them:

[image]

Formula in D1 and drag down is:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C1;"*"&$A$1:$A$2&"*"))=COUNTA($A$1:$A$2);"Yes";"No")`

I think the best way would be having the whitelist words in separate cells.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, I will try the second formula and split the whitelist strings into seprrste cells as you suggest 